# jq recursively delete values that appear in array anywhere in schema

Tags: arrays, json, sed, jq, recursive-datastructures

I'm trying to find out how to use jq to remove a certain value that occurs anywhere in the schema in an array.

In this case i'm trying to remove agent4 from anywhere inside an array underneath the field labelled agents.

This is what I have so far

```
jq '..|.agents? | select(. != null) |  map(select(. != "agent4"))'
```

But that just creates the changed data and I don't know how to re-assign it to the path.

I originally tried using sed for this but its definitely not the tool to use so I switched to jq.

```
   {
      "environments": {
        "default": {
          "machines": {
            "dev-machine": {
              "agents": [
                "agent1",
                "agent2",
                "agent3",
                "agent4"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "environments2": {         
         "agents": [
            "agent1",
            "agent2",
            "agent3",
            "agent4"
         ] 
      }
    }
```

However this just outputs

```
[
  "agent1",
  "agent2",
  "agent3"
]
[
  "agent1",
  "agent2",
  "agent3"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `walk`:

```
walk( if type == "object" and has("agents") 
      then .agents |= map(select(. != "agent4"))
      else . end )
```

If you want to remove the value from all arrays, wherever they occur:

```
walk( if type == "array" then map(select(. != "agent4")) else . end )
```

If you want a more flexible solution, you could, for example, replace `"agent4"` by `$value`, and then set `$value` on the command-line, e.g.  using `--arg value VALUE` if VALUE is a string, or `--argjson value VALUE` as appropriate.

If your jq does not have `walk`, simply prepend its definition, which is available (for example) from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses [path](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#path(path_expression)) to find "agent4" and verify it appears within "agents" before removing it with [delpaths](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#delpaths(PATHS))

```
delpaths([ path(..|select(.=="agent4")) | select(.[-2]=="agents") ])
```

Sample Run (assumes data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -M 'delpaths([ path(..|select(.=="agent4")) | select(.[-2]=="agents") ])' data.json
{
  "environments": {
    "default": {
      "machines": {
        "dev-machine": {
          "agents": [
            "agent1",
            "agent2",
            "agent3"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "environments2": {
    "agents": [
      "agent1",
      "agent2",
      "agent3"
    ]
  }
}
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/-SlYr9tYjn)

Here is another way using [reduce](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce), [leaf_paths](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#paths,paths(node_filter),leaf_paths), [getpath](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#getpath(PATHS)) and [delpaths](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#delpaths(PATHS)):

```
reduce leaf_paths as $p (.;
  if $p[-2]=="agents" and getpath($p)=="agent4" then delpaths([$p]) else . end
)
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/gHGkdx8nJR)